# Boost.Log - How to create a sink with one frontend and two backends

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I'm new to Boost.Log and I'm trying to configure a logging system, so that I have the logs in a file and to be able to access the logs within code.

I managed to get the file backend to work (filename is okay and rotation also works) but now I'm trying to add the functionality that I can access the created logs in source code (I want to display them in the UI).

Do I use an additional text stream backend for this? If so, how do I add another backend to my existing sink?

Here's what I've done:

```
logging::add_common_attributes();
logging::core::get()->set_filter(trivial::severity >= trivial::trace);

// add a sink with file backend
auto fsSink = logging::add_file_log(
    keywords::file_name = "..\\Logs\\%Y%m%d_Tracing_%H%M%S.log",
    keywords::rotation_size = 2* 1024 * 1024,
    keywords::open_mode = std::ios_base::app);

// set format of log entries - example:
// 000001: [2021-04-07 08:03:21.368897] info    : Test message
// log entries have fix width for line id and severity so that all message are aligned
fsSink->set_formatter
(
    expr::stream <<
    std::right << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0') << expr::attr<unsigned int>("LineID") <<
    ": [" << expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") << "] " <<
    std::left << std::setw(7) << std::setfill(' ') << trivial::severity << " : " <<
    expr::smessage
);

fsSink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);
```

It would be really nice if someone could help me with that.

**Edit**

Okay now I set up a second sink with stream backend because I want it to format the logs a bit different.

Initialization of stream sink:

```
boost::shared_ptr<sinks::text_ostream_backend> backend =
    boost::make_shared<sinks::text_ostream_backend>();

backend->add_stream(boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream>(&std::clog, boost::null_deleter()));

boost::shared_ptr<sink_t> streamSink(new sink_t(backend));

streamSink->set_formatter(expr::stream <<
    ": [" << expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") << "] " <<
    expr::smessage);

streamSink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);
core->add_sink(streamSink);
```

Now the big question is: How can I access that stream to redirect it into an UI element? Or is it default to the console (which I'm not using in an UI application) without the possibility to change ?

Comment: I would not bother with streams and implement your own sink backend that would output log records to your UI. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension.html#log.extension.sinks

Comment: Okay thanks for the hint. My situation is that I have three different ListBoxes in my UI (one each for error, info and debug severity) which I want to fill according to the severity level.

I will check for writing my own sink. Thanks!